# XML Schema - make empty elements invalid

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, validation

Should be simple but I cannot find any information on this anywhere.  I want to make some simple elements required, therefore invalidate the XML if some of the elements are empty. I have tried using the nillable attribute but this does not work. I have had to add limitations to the number of characters needed and then remove white space to get this working but it seems really lon winded, am I misssing something?

eg.

```
       <xsd:element name="productImageURL">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                <xsd:maxLength value="450"/>
                <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> 
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
```

Comment: I have come accross another issue which I cannot find a work around at all.  I need to be able to set a simple element as an integer but allow it to also be empty.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

It is the way it is with the XML Schema. Another option could be to use the xsd:pattern facet... Readability though is much better the way you've done it; most people struggle reading patterns such as regular expressions...